# wildcard doesn't working?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
SELECT _cotM.Customer_ID, _cotM.Material_ID
FROM dbo.COT_Monthly AS cot 
INNER JOIN
dbo.vw_Dim_Material AS matr ON cot.Material_ID = matr.Material_ID  
GROUP BY _cotM.Customer_ID, _cotM.Material_ID
```

I have sql code and have result 25855 rows

but when i add `where matr.Brand <> '%VIT%'` upper group by the result still 25855 rows.

but when i delete wildcard `where matr.Brand <> 'VIT'` the result became 25089.

i wandering why the result like this ?

is i am wrong using wildcard or else?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Did you try where matr.Brand NOT like '%VIT%'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcards only work with [`LIKE` clauses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), so change the condition:

```
WHERE matr.Brand NOT LIKE '%VIT%'
```

Answer (score 0):

as **Matt** says use `where matr.Brand not like '%VIT%'`,read more about [wildcard](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

Comment: -1. `[^VIT]` does _not_ match "not `VIT`." Read the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: Why do you think that? Sorry, but you're wrong. `[^VIT]` only matches a single character.